# Calendar Week in gantt chart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there an easy way to show the calendar week (e.g. Week 3, Week 4...etc) using a `kendo ui gantt week header`?

I found out that I can set the `weekHeaderTemplate` within the views but i don't find any option to get the calendar week.

```
{
  type: "week",
  selected: true, 
  slotSize: 70,
  title: "14 days"
  weekHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("#=kendo.toString(start, 'dd')#")
}
```

What would be the correct template to use?